# How to launch two turtlebots on one ROS master

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everybody,

For my project I have to navigate two Turtlebot3's parallel to each other. To do this, I want to send way-points to both turtlebot's simultaneously, using one ROSmaster (my laptop). Sending way-points to one turtlebot works fine, but I can't figure out how to connect both turtlebots to the ROSmaster at the same time. Does anybody know how to connect two turtlebots3 to one ROSmaster or where I have to start searching?

I'm using ROS1 Melodic and turtlebot3.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392374/how-to-launch-two-turtlebots-on-one-ros-master/) by [Alex2008](https://answers.ros.org/users/89281/alex2008/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set for each turtlebot a seperate namespace and tf_prefix.

---

Originally posted by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) with karma: 183 on 2021-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex2008](https://answers.ros.org/users/89281/alex2008/) on 2021-12-10**:
Do I need to do this before launching connecting the robots with ssh ubuntu@...? or when the first robot is connected?

**Comment by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) on 2021-12-27**:
This needs to be done in the launchfiles of each robot